# Catching C++ FFI Exception fails in Haskell

Tags: c++, haskell, cabal

When using FFI to C++ in Haskell, I am able to properly catch exceptions when running the function in `cabal repl`, but when running with `cabal run`, the exception is not caught.

A simple cabal project that exhibits the problem is included below:

**exception.cabal**:

```
name:                exception
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10
executable exception
  main-is:             Main.hs
  c-sources: main.cxx
  build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  extra-libraries:     stdc++
```

main.cxx:

```
# include <exception>
# include <stdexcept>

extern "C" int hs_exception() try
{
  throw std::logic_error("THIS FAILS!");
} catch(...) {
}
```

and

**Main.hs**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Foreign.C.Types (CInt(..))


main = print c_hs_exception

foreign import ccall unsafe "hs_exception"
    c_hs_exception :: CInt
```

Working from the **REPL (i.e GHCI)**:

```
cabal repl
*Main> main
0
```

But failing when compiled with **GHC and ran**:

```
cabal run
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::logic_error: THIS FAILS!
[1]    12781 abort      cabal run
```

**My compilers**:

```
➜ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
➜ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Win 8.1 (ghc 7.6.3), at least the `cabal run`, since `cabal repl` doesn't work in that configuration with FFI. Note: if anyone wants to reproduce this on Windows, make sure that you rename `main.cxx` to `main_c.cxx` or something similar, due to the case-insensitivity of Windows.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Linux either, but OS X is often, well, Different. If you're still having this issue please file a bug report at https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Mac-specific, and was reported as [GHC bug 11829](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11829). The fix is to pass the flag `-lto_library` (LTO = link time optimization) to Clang's linker. This can be done with an executable section of a .cabal file like so:

```
executable myprog
  ...
  if os(darwin)
    ld-options: -lto_library
```

Or the flag `-optl-lto_library` if calling `ghc` directly.

Note that this will incorrectly recommend you write `extra-libraries: to_library` instead, which will not work.